# Excel How to get specific characters from different cells based on same value

Tags: excel, formula

I would like to know if it's possible to have some formula or VBA or other feature to get the specific characters from two or more different cells based on same value which grouped between the underscore. I am using this formula at the moment

`=LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2)-1)`

on column B to get the characters from Column A. for example:

[image: Current]

Now what I want is something like this along with the comma:

[image: Expected1]

If it's not too much to ask already, is it also possible to add "&" to the cell, for example:

[image: Expected2]

if not than it's totally okay as this is only for aesthetic.

I hope it makes sense. Kindly let me know if it's possible. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: So these are grouped based on the values between the underscores?

Comment: yes. what I am trying to get is the order number(s) based on value after the first underscore. aaaa, bbbb, cccc and so on.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't think it's possible with a formula. You'll need to code something in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the answer from this [Forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/help-to-get-characters-from-different-cells-based-on-same-character.1208139/).

So basically create two helper column (Column A and B) and then input below formula by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER on other column (Column D).

`=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,A2,IF(($B$2:$B$10=B2)*($A$2:$A$10<>A2),$A$2:$A$10,"")),","," &",COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,B2)-1)`

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91UkB.png)